# Solving integral $\int\frac{\sin x}{1+x\cos x}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How I can find the anti-derivative?
$$\int\frac{\sin x}{1+x\cos x}dx$$

Comment: [Looks ugly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%28x%29+%2F+%281+%2B+x+cos+x%29).

Comment: Have you tried using the simplification of expressions option?

Comment: No. What is that?

Comment: take $t=1+xcos(x) $

Comment: $ dt=(cosx-xsinx)dx$

Comment: And where do you arrive ?

Comment: If no bounds, I am skeptical concerning the existence of a closed form solution.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: [Liouville](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and [Risch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) are skeptical as well. :-)

Comment: I guess @ClaudeLeibovici is right!

Answer (score 1):

By using the formula http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/math/7/2/a/72a1058ad2087aec467af24bddcf9479.png, we have $\int\dfrac{\sin x}{1+x\cos x}dx=x\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^{2^n-1}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+1}\sin\dfrac{mx}{2^n}}{2^n+mx\cos\dfrac{mx}{2^n}}+C$

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for “cheating”, but it is as it seems: Wolfram|Alpha states it is *not solvable “in terms of standard mathematical functions”* (which should then be true).

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%ABsinx%2F%281%2Bxcosx%29dx

Are you sure this is the correct integral?

Comment: There are many integrals that Wolfram Alpha can't solve, but which have solutions. That being said this is probably not one of them...

Comment: Strange. I am used to Wolfram Alpha having solved _way_ more complex integrals… seems I am going to grab a piece of paper now.